# Sahara ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Tags: openstack

I have Ubuntu  OpenStack Icehouse To install Sahara I am using [this guide](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/sahara/userdoc/installation.guide.html):

When I try to create dabase schema

`sahara-db-manage --config-file /etc/sahara/sahara.conf upgrade head` and I found:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "sahara-venv/bin/sahara-db-manage", line 10, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/db/migration/cli.py", line 110, in main
>       CONF.command.func(config, CONF.command.name)
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/db/migration/cli.py", line 49, in do_upgrade_downgrade
>       do_alembic_command(config, cmd, revision, sql=CONF.command.sql)
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/db/migration/cli.py", line 30, in do_alembic_command
>       getattr(alembic_cmd, cmd)(config, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 165, in upgrade
>       script.run_env()
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/script.py", line 382, in run_env
>       util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/util.py", line 241, in load_python_file
>       module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/compat.py", line 79, in load_module_py
>       mod = imp.load_source(module_id, path, fp)
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/db/migration/alembic_migrations/env.py", line 95, in 
>       run_migrations_online()
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/db/migration/alembic_migrations/env.py", line 79, in run_migrations_online
>       poolclass=pool.NullPool)
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/**init**.py", line 362, in create_engine
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 74, in create
>       dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
>     File "/home/ash/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/connectors/mysqldb.py", line 64, in dbapi
>       return **import**('MySQLdb')
>   ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

I tried `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

But the problem is not solved.

Comment: Did the install go without any errors?

Comment: yes I did not face any error when installing:
python-setuptools python-virtualenv python-dev